# Iterating enum of enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a structure some-thing like

```
public class EnumTest{
     enum fauna
     {
         Animals, Birds;

         enum Animals
         {
              Tiger("tiger"),
              Lion("lion");

              String name;

              Animals(String name)
              {
                   this.name = name; 
              }
         }

         enum Birds
         {
              Peacock("peacock"),
              owl("Owl");

              String name;

              Birds(String name)
              {
                   this.name = name; 
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Now I couldn't find a way to iterate over the enum fauna to print the names of enum animals and birds. Is there any way to do it??

Comment: can you post up the errors that you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't group enums like this. The enum `Birds` is distinct from the `Birds` value inside the `fauna` enum. The usual way to do it is to add a field which is also an enum:

```
enum Fauna {
    enum Type { MAMMAL, BIRD }

    TIGER(Type.MAMMAL), 
    LION(Type.MAMMAL), 
    PEACOCK(Type.BIRD), 
    OWL(Type.BIRD);

    private final Type type;

    Fauna(Type type) { this.type = type; }

}
```

If you only want the animals of a specific type, for example all `BIRD`s, you will unfortunately have to write a helper method to do that, iterating over all the `Fauna` values and picking those of the correct type. (Unless you're running Java 8, in which case it's just `Stream.of(Fauna.values()).filter(f -> f.type == BIRD).toList()` or something similar).

Comment: `Stream.of(Fauna.values()).filter...` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not very sure that this is what you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumTest.fauna[] values = EnumTest.fauna.values();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(values[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access enum directly,

```
for(Animals an:Animals.values()){
        System.out.println(an.name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have large tree-like structure in enum you should consider using composite pattern.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
interface Creature {
    String getName();
}

enum fauna {
    Animals(Animals.class), Birds(Birds.class);
    Class<Creature> i;
    fauna(Class i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    enum Animals implements Creature {
        Tiger("tiger"), Lion("lion");
        String name;
        Animals(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    enum Birds implements Creature {
        Peacock("peacock"), owl("Owl");
        String name;
        Birds(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(fauna e : fauna.values()) {
        for(Creature x : e.i.getEnumConstants()) {
            System.out.print(x.getName() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
tiger lion peacock Owl
```