# C# having Enums of Enums

Tags: c#, enums

Assuming I have an enum category with some values:

```
enum Category {
ProgrammingBooks
CookingBooks
}
```

and I want each enum to have his own enum, for instance:
ProgrammingBooks will hold:

```
enum ProgrammingBooks {
CSharp,
Java,
Cpp
}
```

I saw a solution suggesting this:

```
enum Fauna {
enum Type { MAMMAL, BIRD }

TIGER(Type.MAMMAL), 
LION(Type.MAMMAL), 
PEACOCK(Type.BIRD), 
OWL(Type.BIRD);

private final Type type;

Fauna(Type type) { this.type = type; }

}
```

with the usage:

```
Stream.of(Fauna.values()).filter(f -> f.type == BIRD).toList()
```

However, I'm just a beginner and I look for something that even if I do not know and should learn, wont go hardcore on me. I do not understand the example I mentioned (which I found on StackOverFlow).

Comment: Looks more like Java than C#.

Comment: You should really be creating classes if your enums need their own enums.  You're stretching the purpose of enums otherwise.

Comment: For reference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605628/iterating-enum-of-enums appears to be where this example comes from; and, as @UweKeim says, it's Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use classes or interfaces. For example:

```
public enum Category
{
    ProgrammingBooks,
    CookingBooks
}

public interface IBook
{
    Category BookType { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Author { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class ProgrammingBook: IBook
{
    public ProgrammingBook()
    {
        this.BookType = Category.ProgrammingBooks;
    }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Category BookType { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class CookBook : IBook
{
    public CookBook()
    {
        this.BookType = Category.CookingBooks;
    }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Category BookType { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

If you want to support "sub-types" you could provide properties that only belong to a specific class and not into the interface because not every book is about programming. For example:

```
public enum ProgrammingLanguage
{
    CSharp,
    Java,
    Cpp
}

public class ProgrammingBook: IBook
{
    // a constructor that takes the ProgrammingLanguage as argument
    public ProgrammingBook(ProgrammingLanguage language)
    {
        this.BookType = Category.ProgrammingBooks;
        this.Language = language;
    }

    public ProgrammingLanguage Language { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Category BookType { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Why i use interfaces at all? Because all books have something in common(f.e. they all have a title and an author). So you can benefit from [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)):

```
var library = new List<IBook>();
var book1 = new ProgrammingBook(ProgrammingLanguage.CSharp) {Title = "C# in Depth", Author = "Jon Skeet"};
var book2 = new CookBook() { Title = "Everyday Superfood", Author= "Jamie Oliver" };
library.Add(book1);
library.Add(book2);

// now you can loop all and you know that all books have these properties
foreach (IBook book in library)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} Type: {1}", book.Title, book.BookType.ToString());
}
```

or if you only want to get programming-books:

```
foreach (IBook book in library.Where(b => b.BookType == Category.ProgrammingBooks))
{
   // ...
}
```

the same with LINQ's `Enumerable.OfType` method which just checks the type:

```
foreach (IBook book in library.OfType<ProgrammingBook>())
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Jesus christ, i was writting almost the same code. I think that's what he wants. +1

Comment: @LeandroSoares --- woooahhh, settle down...

Comment: Thank you Tim!
Leandro, thank you as well for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Enum is just a representation of an integer with text. It cannot hold sub categories or anything but an integer.

You should create a class for the categories and hold an enum of the sub categories in each of them.

```
public class ProgrammingBook
{
   public BookType Type{get;set;}
}

enum BookType {
   CSharp,
   Java,
   Cpp
}
```

Comment: Did you accidentially post your comment as an answer?

Comment: sounds better, can have an example?

Comment: I've updated my answer